# Contar quantas vezes cada elemento apareceu com outro em um array

Tags: php

Possuo estes arrays como referência:

```
$a_controle = array ('A','B','C','D','E','F');

var_dump($array_final) =>
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string 'B' (length=1)
      2 => string 'C' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string 'B' (length=1)
      2 => string 'D' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string 'C' (length=1)
      2 => string 'E' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'D' (length=1)
      1 => string 'E' (length=1)
      2 => string 'F' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'A' (length=1)
      1 => string 'B' (length=1)
      2 => string 'P' (length=1)
```

Como posso contar quantas vezes cada elemento do `$a_controle` saiu junto com outro no `$array_final`?

Por exemplo:

- O **A** apareceu com **B** 3 vezes
- O **A** apareceu com **C** 2 vezes
- O **A** apareceu com **D** 1 vezes
- O **A** apareceu com **E** 1 vez
- O **A** apareceu com **F** 0 vezes

Acabou a verificação do **A** passa para o próximo elemento do `$a_controle` (elemento B):

- O **B** apareceu com **C** 1 vez
- O **B** apareceu com **D** 1 vez
- O **B** apareceu com **E** 0 vez
- O **B** apareceu com **F** 0 vez

Acabou a verificação do **B** passa para o próximo elemento do `$a_controle` (elemento C).

Acabou a verificação do **C** passa para o próximo elemento do `$a_controle` (elemento D).

Acabou a verificação do **D** passa para o próximo elemento do `$a_controle` (elemento E).

Acabou a verificação do **E** passa para o próximo elemento do `$a_controle` (elemento F).

Assim sucessivamente para um array de tamanho desconhecido. É possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar um `foreach` para chegar ao sub array a analisar, e depois utilizar dois `for` para verificar cada elemento nos seus vizinhos:

```
$a_controle = Array('A','B','C','D','E','F');
$array_final = Array(
    Array("A","B","C"),
    Array("A","B","D"),
    Array("A","C","E"),
    Array("D","E","F"),
    Array("A","B","P")
); 

$apareceu_com = Array();

foreach ($array_final as $sub_array_final){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sub_array_final); ++$i){
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($sub_array_final); ++$j){
            $elem1 = $sub_array_final[$i];
            $elem2 = $sub_array_final[$j];

            if ($i != $j){ //se não é o proprio elemento
                if (isset($apareceu_com[$elem1][$elem2])){
                    $apareceu_com[$elem1][$elem2]++;
                }
                else {
                    $apareceu_com[$elem1][$elem2] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($apareceu_com);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
[A] => Array
    (
        [B] => 3
        [C] => 2
        [D] => 1
        [E] => 1
        [P] => 1
    )

[B] => Array
    (
        [A] => 3
        [C] => 1
        [D] => 1
        [P] => 1
    )
...
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/W7I6qB)

Comment: Mas não entendi essa saída. Porque a letra D está como 2? Seria A saiu com D 2 vezes? Porque se for está incorreto.

Comment: @jsnow A letra `D` está como 2 porque saiu 2 vezes. Ela está no subarray[1] como último elemento e no subarray[3] como primeiro elemento. Escrevendo de outra forma `$array_final[1][2]` tem `D` e  `$array_final[3][0]` também tem `D`

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu. Eu gostaria de saber quantas vezes CADA elemento saiu com OUTRO utilizando o `$a_controle`. Do jeito que expliquei lá em cima. Preciso que o seja verificado o A com B, C, D, E, F. Depois B com C, D, E, F. Depois C com D, E, F e assim sucessivamente para cada letra.

Comment: @jsnow Também já editei a resposta, que penso agora ter acertado no que pretendia, e por isso pedia-lhe que confirmasse

Comment: perfeito, exatamente isso que eu pretendia. Irei estudar seu código para entender melhor o que está acontecendo aí. Obrigado!